# How I am supposed to translate this spark scala line to java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, neo4j

I am trying out [spark-neo4j connector](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector). In examples of this link, I found following line:

```
neo.cypher("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN id(n)").loadRdd[Long].mean
```

I am trying to convert this line to Java equivalent. But I am not getting how should I proceed for lack of my understanding of scala. The issue is with `loadRdd[Long]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about spark, but I would expect the java would be:

```
neo.cypher("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN id(n)").<long>loadRdd().mean()
```